# Linked files after saving website in Windows

Tags: windows, web, filesystems, explorer

Saving a website from inside a browser to your local disk, you end up with

```
Google.htm
Google_files/
```

When you delete or move one of these items, both of them are deleted or moved. Do you know how this is achieved? I tested this on NTFS and FAT formatted drives, works on both.

And a follow-up question: workarounds are obvious, but how to remove this bond from a set of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an explorer.exe (Windows GUI shell) feature, not the file system. If you remove via an application that uses other mechanisms (`remove` function in C), this doesn't happen.
Calling `del` from a command prompt will also delete just the html file.

Comment: Do you know where these 'attributes' are persisted?

Comment: I was wondering where the link is stored. Is it somewhere in the registry or is it some kind of file attribute? (Although you say it's not part of the FS)

Comment: My guess is that it's not stored. the directory has the same name as the html file (w/o the htm extension + _files suffix).

Comment: spot on! I just confirmed this by manually creating this scenario. html and htm work fine. It appears it's handled on-the-fly. Thanks a bunch!